# Char to Hex parameter

Tags: java, awtrobot

I'm attempting in making the Robot typing method a lot simpler.
Most of the keycodes in `KeyEvent` are hex codes.

Plan:

1. `String` to `char[]`
2. for-each through the `char[]`
3. find hex value of `(int)char`
4. keyPress(hex value of `(int)char`)
5. keyRelease(hex value of `(int)char`)

What I have so far:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Driver
{
    private static Robot r;
    public static void send(String phrase)
    {
        char[] chars = phrase.toCharArray();
        for (char letter:chars)
        {
            //int hex = hex value of (int)letter
            //r.keyPress(hex);
            //r.keyRelease(hex);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        try
        {
            r = new Robot();
            r.delay(5000);
            send("Hello World");
        }
        catch(AWTException e)
        {
            //Nothing
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please state a specific problem with your code as it is. What do you want to achieve that your code currently does not?

Comment: Do you need an hex string or do you only need an integer value ? If you are using ASCII characters you can cast a char into an int.

Comment: the keyPress needs to take a parameter that looks like 0x41 for it to press A I need to figure out a way to make a char into a hex. And I can't pass a string. so it should look like keyPress(0x4b);

Comment: You can't pass a string it has to be an int. So doing a r.keyPress(Integer.toHexString((int)letter); won't work

Comment: @KonradWright please apdate your code to show the signature of your methods `keyPress` and `keyRelease`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keycodes for ASCII letters are equals to their uppercase char value.
So you could do the following:

```
char[] chars = phrase.toUpperCase().toCharArray();
for (char letter:chars)
{
    int keyCode = (int)letter;
    r.keyPress(keyCode);
    r.keyRelease(keyCode);
}
```

With this loop, the string "Hello World" will give "hello world".
It won't work for things like exclamation points.

Furthermore, if you wan't the robot to send uppercase letters you will have to simulate a press on the shift key or on the caps lock key.

Not sure this method is reliable though. You may as well do a lot a if/else (or a switch) to return the correct key code constant from java.awt.event.KeyEvent.

Comment: Not exactly the kind of answer I was looking for, but I'm feeling this is the closest I'll get. I really just wanted to know how to pass a hex as a parameter. keyPress(0x4b) for instance.

Comment: 0x4b is a perfectly usable value but it is the same as writing 75 or (int)'K'

Comment: So how would I get a char to hex value using that +'K' deal?

Comment: I think the point is that `0x4b == (int)'K'` - they are just different ways of writing the exact same thing.  You can look up the hex values of chars at http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 1):

This work, but it would have problem with special characters like "Hello World é ç", see output.
It would like better to use \unnnn UniCode paradigm.

```
        final char[] chars = phrase.toCharArray();
        for (final char c : chars) {
            try {
                final byte[] tabB = (c + "").getBytes("UTF-8");
// You can replace "UTF-8" by : System.getProperty("sun.jnu.encoding"), 
                for (final byte element : tabB) {
                    System.out.format("%s\t0x%s\n", element,
                            Integer.toHexString(element));
                }
            } catch (final UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
        }
```

Output :

```
72  0x48
101 0x65
108 0x6c
108 0x6c
111 0x6f
32  0x20
87  0x57
111 0x6f
114 0x72
108 0x6c
100 0x64
32  0x20
-61 0xffffffc3
-87 0xffffffa9
32  0x20
-61 0xffffffc3
-89 0xffffffa7
```

with System.getProperty("sun.jnu.encoding") --> ISO-8859-15 on my PC

```
72  0x48
101 0x65
108 0x6c
108 0x6c
111 0x6f
32  0x20
87  0x57
111 0x6f
114 0x72
108 0x6c
100 0x64
32  0x20
-23 0xffffffe9
32  0x20
-25 0xffffffe7
```